# Where can I find a list of all family names containing Schild/Schilt?

Tags: person-names, list

I've been searching for a while but can't find any list of all *family names* (but current and historic) containing the element Schild/Schilt, either as a prefix or a suffix.

It's not even mentioned as a prefix or a suffix in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_family_name_affixes), and another Wikipedia site only gives Schild as a prefix but isn't limited to *family names*, [here](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Pr%C3%A4fixindex/Schild).

Comment: The question you should be asking is "Where can I find a list of all names?". Once you have the list it'll be easy to filter out the ones you want. That's assuming such a list exists

Comment: *Schild* in family names usually means *buckler* and this is a common heraldic item. So you pretty sure will find it in **any** combination. → Such a list cannot be exhaustive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about German language. It is a question about search techniques.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bummer

Comment: I agree with PiedPiper that this is about finding a list of all family names. Just wanted to add that you should specify, whether you are looking for family names that a currently in use, or if you also want to find extinct family names.

Comment: @Arsak Thanks a lot

Comment: Schild is far more common, "Schilt" looks like some archaised version to me.

Comment: @peterh It is indeed. Middle High German, and there are still names using it. I would even be interested in knowing all the Old High German scild/scilt names, but I'm shy to ask after my question has been voted to be off topic

Comment: Jews had a non-German name roughly until the medieval ages. Then some emperor made for them obligatory to adopt German names (religious Jews still use their Jewish name for religious purposes). These names are characteristic and make people with Jewish ancestry partially identifiable. That *schild names is one of them. It is also the reason, why so many people, particularly in the U.S., has a German-sounding name, while they have actually Jewish ancestry. Most common example is Rotschild (means "red name plate"). Or there was a well-known physicist Schwarzschild ("black name plate").

Comment: While correct for the medieval, this neglects the 19th century, when German Jews assimilated into the arising civic society and the borders between Jews and Christians crumbled apart as well as the borders between Germans and Poles. Mixed families of all four kinds were not the norm but still common.

Comment: There were still family names that were predominantly Jewish, and recognized as such. Of course that didn't mean that everyone with such a name had to be a Jew.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with *any* word you choose, not only *Schild* or *Schilt*, because you can create potentially infinite compositions. These are only two examples with *Schild*, one in each direction:

- *Schild*kröte → *Schild*krötenfutter → *Schild*krötenfutterverkauf → *Schild*krötenfutterverkaufsangebot → ...
- Verkehrs*schild* → Straßenverkehrs*schild* → Landstraßenverkehrs*schild* → ...

Comment: Oh, now I notice that you might really only want *family names*, not names in the sense of terms for things.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd specified that in my question. I've corrected that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page will help you: [Deutsche Nachnamen](https://www.deutsche-nachnamen.de/index.php/herkunft-a-z)

Comment: Can you use that to look for name endings though?

Comment: Yes you can. If you eg. search for "bach" are all possible names that end in Bach

Comment: You can also buy and download one of the files on this homepage and search in a text editor with Regex or code your own script.

https://www.datendieter.de/item/Liste_deutscher_Nachnamen

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Walzenbach. Awesome name you have. Elsewhere on the web I made queries about the Wittlesbach

Comment: @Johan88 Thanks :)

Comment: @SaschaWalzenbach The site is in German so I don't understand it. I was able to get a very small list of Schild names, but only 10 or 15, meaning their database is very small or, more likely, I am doing something wrong. Are you getting a massive list of Schild names on this site, and if so can you please instruct me (and edit your answer to include those instructions please)?

Comment: With "shield" you get on this page really only 10 results.
The other homepage would have a larger DB but also costs something ... Sorry.
I still searched but found no other useful page.

Comment: @SaschaWalzenbach Thanks so much Sascha. Really appreciated. Too bad this site doesn't give more or I'd give u the green tick, but thanks a lot ;)